# Нужно вывести максимальное число из чисел, которое встречается в матрице больше 1 раза

Tags: c, массивы, условия

```
max = a[n][m];
for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for( j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for( k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            for( l = 0; l < m; l++)
            {
                if (a[i][j] == a[k][l])
                {
                    if(a[i][j] > max)
                    {
                        max = a[i][j];  
                        break;    
                    }                                     
                }

            }
        }
    }
} 
printf("%d",a[i][j]);
```

подскажите что здесь не так

Comment: `is_in_matrix_more_once()`. Шутка :) Или вы всерьез думаете, что есть такая *стандартная* функция?

Comment: нет, я спрашиваю какой нужен алгоритм для этого)

Comment: @Harry конечно нет. Это ведь функция, а не константа... Должно быть что-то вроде matrix.getDublicates()

Comment: @SanyaAllen. Ну смотри, если в матрице под другим индексом есть то же значение, то, скорее всего, оно встречается чаще одного раза

Comment: Ну как вариант: записать матрицу в одномерный массив, отсортировать в порядке убывания и уже в этом массиве найти дубликаты, которые удобно расположены друг за другом.

Comment: здесь "не так" все, начиная со строчки `max = a[n][m];`

Comment: @igor можете подсказать если знаете, как написать этот код по-нормальному?)

Comment: Я убежден, что в таких задачах написать код - не главное. Вам следует описать словами, как сделать то, что требуется. Тогда Вы сами сразу увидите все ошибки в логике кода в вопросе.

Comment: @igor да вроде в голове придумал, но реализовать в код не вышло, а так я  хотел чтобы система отобрала числа что повторяются и с них искала максимальное значение.

Comment: "чтобы система отобрала одинаковые числа и с них искала максимальное значение" - не является описанием алгоритма. В голове - недостаточно. Надо - на бумаге или в текстовом файле ).

Comment: @igor усовершенствовал код что выше и всё получилось, спасибо что показали как решать подобные задачи!

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов решения:

1. Взять отдельный массив с нулевыми элементами и увеличивать на единицу значение, которое хранится по индексу равному значению элемента исходной матрицы.
2. Затем отбросить из массива все элементы со значениями меньше 2.
3. Последний оставшийся индекс массива будет искомым значением.